# In Wordpress, $wp_filesystem->get_contents is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to make code that get contents from a remote URL and save it to a local file.

I am using `$wp_filesystem->get_contents()` and it doesn't work. The return value is empty.

`wp_remote_get` function doesn't work on my server, but `$wp_filesystem->get_contents` doesn't give me the right result.

I've added `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct')` in mty wp_config.php
but it does nothing.

Code follows:

```
global $wp_filesystem;
$response = $wp_filesystem->get_contents(
                add_query_arg( array(
                    'code'   => $code,
                    'server' => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],
                    'action' => 'downloadContents',
                    'path'   => urlencode( $kind . '/' . $demo )
                ), KCT_API_URI )
            );
```

Comment: You won't be able to use the filesystem API to make HTTP requests, I'm afraid. You'll probably have more success trying to find out why wp_remote_get doesn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify why "wp_remote_get function doesn't work on my server"? That sounds like an issue that needs tackling.